# Converting a list of POJO's to a YAML file in JAVA

Tags: java, yaml

I  have found many examples in StackOverflow but I guess none of them are facing this problem which I have:

I am trying to convert a List of POJOs to a YAML format and writing the file onto the disk.
I am using Snake Yaml with this dependancy in my Pom:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
   <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
   <version>1.18</version>
  </dependency>
```

My code :

```
Pojo po = new Pojo();
po.setProperty1("po1");
po.setProperty2("po2");
po.setProperty3("po3");

DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
options.setPrettyFlow(true);

Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
String s = yaml.dump(po);

Output :
- !! com.test.Pojo
  Property1:"po1"
  Property2:"po2"
  Property3:"po3"

Desired output:
- Property1:"po1"
  Property2:"po2"
  Property3:"po3"
```

When I use `yaml.dump(myObject)` it also prints the object name along with its properties. Is there a way I can get the desired output?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/: Reading the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-dumping-yaml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Representer`](http://javadox.com/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/org/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer.html).

Setting the class tag to `Tag.MAP` should hide the class name.

```
Representer representer = new Representer();
representer.addClassTag(Pojo.class, Tag.MAP);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Davide Lorenzo Marino - that definately solved the problem , but it adds braces and is not abiding to block style, representer.addClassTag(Product.class, Tag.MAP);     representer.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.FLOW);                                           This is how i get the ouput-> {property1: po1, property2: po2, property3:po3 }
  I am looking for Strict block format

Comment: I played around with the options a little bit and this initalizing Yaml object with dumperOptions & representer solved the problem... Thanks !!